# Trying to understand Node JS routing code

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to understand [one](https://github.com/tngan/express-saml2) of the open source implementations to achieve SAML based SSO and I am having trouble understanding the following express router method from [this](https://github.com/tngan/express-saml2/blob/master/examples/sp1/routes/index.js) class:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(arguments);
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'sp1 - My Application',
            user: req.user
        });
    }else{
      console.log('not authentcated sending to authenticate');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

My question is :

```
where exactly the code is setting `isAuthenticated` flag to true or false?
```

When I launched /login for the first time, I see it being false but again when I get a redirect from my idp (identity provider) this flag is true and I am going inside the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

This method does come from [passport](https://www.passportjs.org) authentication system,

you can check the function itself [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L74):

```
/**
* Test if request is authenticated.
*
* @return {Boolean}
* @api public
*/
req.isAuthenticated = function() {
  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance._userProperty) {
 property = this._passport.instance._userProperty;
}

 return (this[property]) ? true : false;
};
```